# getting false result when it should return 1 or 0

Tags: excel-formula

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("consumer", I4)),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("compliance", I4))*AND(L4="Complete",AND(P4="Yes",Q4="No")),1,0))
```

I am trying to search a specific column for two values and then compare another two columns to get a return value as 1 or 0 but I am getting a "false"

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you use [`AND()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

```
IF(AND(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("compliance",I4)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("consumer", I4))),L4="Complete",P4="Yes",Q4="No"),1,0)
```

Comment: Did you try the formula? @LBJ It should work.  If not provide data and expected output.  By the way I read your formula and text all four must be true to return 1 or if any are not return 0.

Comment: I tried it but I need to add another search component, did you see the edited formula that I added?

Comment: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("consumer", I4)),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("compliance", I4))*AND(L4="Complete",AND(P4="Yes",Q4="No")),1,0))

Comment: @LBJ please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Hello, I have a new two questions that I am hoping to get answers for, the first one: =IF(AND(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("complete",M81)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("no interaction", S81))),T81="N/A"),0,1)... if M does not equal complete, it give me the answer as 1 how can I modify the formula to give me zero if M does not equal complete? Thanks

Comment: @LBJ New questions get new Post.  Also you need to mark this as correct. by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: I need to count unique records for a specific criteria name & rating. When the rating is high, I get the result with a fraction example, result should be 3, I get 2.25. when the rating is moderate, critical or low it is correct.
=SUM(IF("Alex"='Issues report'!$G$1:$G$387,IF("high"='Issues report'!$ L$1:$ L$387,1/(COUNTIFS('Issues report'!$Z$1:$Z$387,'Issues report'!$AZ$1:$Z$387)),0)))

Comment: @LBJ New questions get new Post

Comment: how do I make a new post?

Comment: Ask a New Question by pressing the `New Question` button.

Comment: sorry I am having a hard time fining the new question button. when I click on ask question it does not take me to new question?